# Using w2ui grid, How to make select/dropdown type have a different items?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, grid, w2ui

How to make dropdown Items change depends on the record?

For example

some_items variable dropdown options are "A","B","C"

new_items1 variable dropdown options are "D","E","F"

new_items2 variable dropdown options are "G","H","I"

```
$('#grid').w2grid({
    name: 'grid',
    show: {
        toolbar: true,
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "recid", caption: "ID", size: "170px", sortable: true, resizeable: true },
        { field: "some_text", caption: "Some Text", size: "170px", sortable: true, resizeable: true },
        { field: "some_dropdown", caption: "Some Dropdown", size: "75px", sortable: true, resizeable: true,
            editable: { type: 'select', items: some_items },
            render: function (record, index, col_index) {
                var html = '';
                for (var s in some_items) {
                    if (some_items[s].id == this.getCellValue(index, col_index)) html = some_items[s].text;
                }
                return html;
            }

        }
    ],
    records: [
        {"recid": 1, "some_text": "Text1", "some_dropdown": new_items1},
        {"recid": 1, "some_text": "Text1", "some_dropdown": new_items2}
    ],
    onChange: function(event){
        console.log(event)
    }
});
```

Is it possible to change the dropdown per record?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, create a dropdown element inside toolbar and after [select](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.onSelect) column bind/load your server side data to dropdown.

**Edit :**
1- add a dropdown element inside toolbar

```
toolbar: {
        items: [
                { type: 'html', html: '<select id="getDropdownData" "></select>' }
               ]
}
```

2- when one column selected bind/load related-data to dropdown

```
     onSelect: function (event) {

          $("#getDropdownData").select2({ width: "160px" });

         var selectedColumnId = w2ui["grid"].get(event["columnId"]);

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: //your url to return column related-data,
                data: {
                    Id: selectedColumnId 
                },
                success: function (data) {
                        for (i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {

                            $(getDropdownData).append($('<option></option>')
                                .attr({ value: data.result[i][0] })
                                .html(data.result[i][1]));
                        }//for                    
                },
               error: function (request, status, error) {
                       alert(request.responseText);
              }
      });

}
```

3- when column unSelect Clear Dropdown Data

```
onUnselect: function (event) {

    $('#getDropdownData').children().remove().end().append('<option selected value="select one column"></option>');

}
```

4- when grid load set width to dropdown

```
onLoad: function (event) {
     $("#getDropdownData").select2({ width: "160px" });
}
```

Comment: It might be better to add some details to you answer

Comment: @vaibhav-garg ı added more details please check